# How to break a long line in .bash_profile

Tags: shell-script, bash-profile

I have a very long line in my .bash_profile, as below:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:$HOME/anaconda2/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/mac/lib:/opt/intel/mkl/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

How do I break this line into multiple lines?

Also, is .bash_profile considered a shell script? If not, what exactly is it categorized as? If I know this, I will be able to look up general formatting guide for this file.

Comment: that's an unusual item at the end of the list; are you perhaps missing a `$` to make it `$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes you are right. A $ sign is missing.

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/intel/mkl/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/mac/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda/lib:$HOME/anaconda2/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Or, with an array and string concatenation:

```bsh
paths=(
    /usr/local/cuda/lib
    "$HOME/anaconda2/lib"
    /usr/local/lib
    /usr/lib
    /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/mac/lib
    /opt/intel/mkl/lib
    ${DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:+"$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"}
)

IFS=:$IFS
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="${paths[*]}"
IFS=${IFS#?}
```

That last item in the array will expand to the value of the `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, or nothing if it's not set or is empty.

The expansion of `"${paths[*]}"` will be the paths joined into a single string delimited by the first character of the `IFS` variable, which we temporarily set to `:`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the line break character: `\`.  Also you should declare and export on two different lines so:

```
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:\
$HOME/anaconda2/lib:\
/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:\
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/mac/lib:\
/opt/intel/mkl/lib:\
$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Your bash profile is a config file and a script of sorts.

Comment: I would consider ~/.bash_profile a script, as it certainly executes commands.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Fair enough.  Updated.

Comment: If I was going to break up the line, I'd break each colon-separated element to its own line, just for legibility.

Comment: @Jesse_b Should there be a `$` sign before the `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` variable at the end of the declaration?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, you didn't have it in the original question so I left it the way it was presented.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's Bash, you can append to a string (`var+=value`). Though you pretty much need a temporary variable here, since you're prefixing the paths to the original value.

```
tmp=/usr/local/cuda/lib
tmp+=:$HOME/anaconda2/lib
tmp+=:/usr/local/lib
tmp+=:/usr/lib
tmp+=:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/mac/lib
tmp+=:/opt/intel/mkl/lib
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$tmp:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
unset tmp
```

Note that like your original snippet, this assumes that `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` is not empty in the beginning. If it is, this'd leave a trailing `:` in it.

---

Alternatively, if your paths don't contain whitespace just put the string in quotes, and remove the whitespace afterwards:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda/lib:
   $HOME/anaconda2/lib:
   /usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:
   /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/mac/lib:
   /opt/intel/mkl/lib:
   $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=${DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH//[[:space:]]}
```

---

This is a bit silly:

```
prepend() { declare -n _n=$1; _n="$2$_n"; }
prepend DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/intel/mkl/lib:
prepend DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/mac/lib:
prepend DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib:
prepend DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib:
prepend DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH "$HOME/anaconda2/lib:"
prepend DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/lib:
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score -1):

I use Stephen Collyer's bash_path_funcs, described in Linux Journal way back in 2000:

https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3768
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3935

The `addpath` function adds an entry to a path only if it is not there in the first place. `delpath -n` deletes all non-existent directories from a path.

You can get the `pathfunc.tgz` file from  https://web.archive.org/web/20061210054813/http://www.netspinner.co.uk:80/Downloads/pathfunc.tgz